# Is there a way to find the root of this error?

Tags: c, linux

Im trying to compile some files with this given gcc command on a server cluster through Mac terminal:

```
gcc -o driver -std=c11 -Wall -W -ggdb3 driver.c ASMParser.c ParseResult.c Generate.o Grader.o
```

And get this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld:Grader.o: file format not recognized; treating as linker script
/usr/bin/ld:Grader.o:1: syntax error
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

but its not very helpful considering Grader.o is a file I didn't even modify, it was provided by the teacher.

Any help on how to fix this? I have compiled it successfully using that gcc command before but after I added a few more implementation details in ASMParser.c it started giving me this error. Im expecting it to create a file called "driver" that I can run like this:

```
./driver "test file" "results.txt"
```

Comment: Backtrack until that change that stopped it from working.

Comment: talk to the teacher. The file is not good for your mac os.

Comment: I just deleted everything that I added and tried to run it - it was working before but not now

Comment: It was working fine before, then stopped

Comment: You are completely sure you have not modified it by accident? Check the modification date or just redownload it. And you have not made ANY changes? Same compiler? Same computer?

Comment: No changes, Im going to try and redownload all the files except the files I modified and try it again ..

Comment: And no modifications to your system? Like updating it?

Comment: Check whether `file Grader.o` reports something sensible — it may be an object file that is for a Linux machine and not a Mac.